# Calulating distance using cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I want to sort list according to a distance formula. Following query is working fine but dont know how to implement this using cakephp.

```
"SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($locality_latitude) ) * cos( radians(locality_latitude) ) * cos( radians( locality_longitude ) - radians($locality_longitude) ) + sin( radians($locality_latitude) ) * sin( radians( locality_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM officers Officer JOIN localities Locality JOIN cities City ON locality.id = officer.locality_id AND city.id = officer.city_id WHERE officer.city_id =$city_id $des ORDER BY instant distance"
```

Comment: Before you reinvent the wheel you might want to look into [geocoding-with-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/). The virtual fields helper wrappers will do all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual field:

```html
public $virtualFields = array(
    'yourDefinition' => 'your calculation'
);
```

see [Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)